Spring Boot 3.2 Validation Logic Changed
I recently noticed that Spring Boot 3.2 has introduced changes to its validation mechanism compared to Spring Boot 2.7.
In Spring Boot 2.7, to validate objects within a list, @Validated was typically applied at the class level. Therefore, in the code example below, the validation logic did not execute, and the controller responded with a 200 status code even if there were validation issues.
However, in Spring Boot 3.2, using just @Valid on the list ensures that each object within the list undergoes validation. As a result, if any validation fails, the controller responds with a 400 status code.
I attempted to find detailed documentation explaining the specific differences between versions 2.7 and 3.2, but I could only locate references mentioning that validation logic has been enhanced starting from Spring 6.1 and Spring Boot 3.2. If anyone has knowledge of the exact differences or access to comprehensive documentation on this topic, I would appreciate learning more.
I looked up what's the difference between 2.7 and 3.2, only things I found that since Spring 6.1 and Spring Boot 3.2, validation logics are advanced and I couldn't find what's changes and difference in detail.
Is anyone who know the difference or a detailed document related to that?
controller
@RestController
public class HelloController {
    @GetMapping("/")
    public String hello() {
        return "Hello World!";
    }

    @PostMapping("/test")
    public String helloPost(@RequestBody @Valid List<HelloRequest> helloRequests) {
        return helloRequests.stream().map(HelloRequest::getName).collect(Collectors.joining(", "));
    }

}

request object
public class HelloRequest {
    @Max(10)
    @NotNull
    private long id;

    @NotNull
    private String name;

    public HelloRequest() {
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

}


request

[
    {
        "id": 12,
        "name": "d",
        "babyRequests": [
            {
                "id": 1
            },
            {
                "id": 1
            }
        ]
    }
]


What happens if you add @Validated to your controller class and change @Valid List<HelloRequest> to List<@Valid HelloRequest>?

@LeeGreiner In Spring Boot 2.7, the validation is working in this case. But in Spring Boot 3.2, the validation is working without adding @Validated to the controller class.
